# Type safe way for cloning generics

Tags: java, generics, lombok

I have a super class:

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class Animal {
   private Integer size;
}
```

and several subclasses for it

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class Dog extends Animal{
   private String color;
}
```

As you can see, both of the above classes are immutable. Also I have a generic class which computes on any subclass of animal. I am creating a new instance of the animal here with increased size.

```
public class GrowAnimal<T extends Animal> {
    public T execute(T animal) {
        // Here I need to explicitly cast to T
        T newAnimal = (T) animal.toBuilder()
              .size(animal.getSize() + 1)
              .build();
        return newAnimal;
    }
}
```

There are several problems with this approach:

1. I cannot make Animal an abstract class
2. It can get pretty unsafe if i have more transformation classes like GrowAnimal
3. If someone adds a new subclass of animal and forgets to add SuperBuilder to it, The GrowAnimal will just copy the super-class attributes.

Is there a better way to clone T? I would want to retain all the other attributes of the animal (for example, color of the dog) unchanged in the new instance created. Instead of cloning, I could use setters to mutate the incoming object but that is a code smell.

Comment: `toBuilder`, `size` gonna return the lombok generated builder object and build will generate the Animal object.

Comment: What is the type of `toBuilder`, `size` and `build`? Is it `<T extends Animal> T`? e.g. `<T extends Animal> T toBuilder() { ... }`

Comment: That's the best you can do in Java. Java has no generic constructor like C# and limited type safety for generics. Casting is fairly common in Java and don't sweat it

Comment: @SwiftMango There are several problems with this approach:
1. I cannot make Animal an abstract class
2. It can get pretty unsafe if i have more transformation classes like `GrowAnimal`
3. If someone adds a new subclass of animal and forgets to add SuperBuilder to it. The cloning will just copy the super-class attributes.

Comment: Ad 3): There is no way to enforce `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder=true)` on subclasses during compile-time. You could write a unit test (e.g. using ArchUnit) or check during runtime if this is critical.

Comment: It seems that there is no elegant way to do this and we are hacking the language to have our way. This seems to be a very common usecase and I am wondering how other people would be handling this.

I guess introducing mutation (setters) is the only elegant way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no (type-)safe way for your approach. The underlying reason is that you cannot enforce `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)` on subclasses with "pure Java" means.

If a subclass only has `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = false)` or even no `@SuperBuilder` at all, this code will compile fine. However, calling `toBuilder()` on an instance of this subclass will not return a builder of that type, but a builder of the nearest superclass with `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)`. Thus, your explicit cast to `T` is marked unsafe by the compiler for a good reason.

If it's just code that you control, you could write a unit test that ensures that all subclasses of `Animal` also have `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)`. A framework that can support you in writing such tests is [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/). With it, you can write things like `classes().that().areAssignableTo(Animal.class).should()` and append your conditions. Remember that the `@SuperBuilder` annotation itself is removed during compilation, so you have to check for the presence of the lombok-generated code.

If `Animal` can be extended by third-party code, you could check during runtime if all subclasses have `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)`.

Or you simply live with the fact that your code in `GrowAnimal` could throw `ClassCastException`s.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use generics. The `execute` method can receive an `Animal` instead of `T` and that should solve it.

Comment: Then the execute method will always return an Animal and the caller will need to explicitly downcast it to Dog (if Dog was given in the input)

Comment: I understand. I think that the best thing you can do in that case is to use setters instead of the builder.